# MySQL get consecutive present with max to min ordering

Tags: mysql

How can I get consecutive present from a table attendance data.

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `a` (`id`, `uid`, `date`, `time`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2020-03-12', '08:01:17', 'a'),
(2, 1, '2020-03-01', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(3, 1, '2020-03-02', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(4, 1, '2020-03-03', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(5, 1, '2020-03-04', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(6, 1, '2020-03-05', '08:01:17', 'l'),
(7, 1, '2020-03-06', '08:01:17', 'l'),
(8, 1, '2020-03-07', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(9, 1, '2020-03-08', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(10, 1, '2020-03-09', '08:01:17', 'l'),
(11, 1, '2020-03-10', '08:00:15', 'p'),
(12, 1, '2020-03-11', '08:02:27', 'p'),
(13, 2, '2020-03-01', '08:11:17', 'a'),
(14, 2, '2020-03-02', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(15, 2, '2020-03-03', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(16, 2, '2020-03-04', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(17, 2, '2020-03-05', '08:01:17', 'l'),
(18, 2, '2020-03-06', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(19, 2, '2020-03-07', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(20, 2, '2020-03-08', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(21, 2, '2020-03-09', '08:01:17', 'l'),
(22, 2, '2020-03-10', '08:00:15', 'p'),
(23, 2, '2020-03-11', '08:02:27', 'p'),
(24, 3, '2020-03-01', '08:11:17', 'l'),
(25, 3, '2020-03-02', '08:01:17', 'l'),
(26, 3, '2020-03-03', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(27, 3, '2020-03-04', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(28, 3, '2020-03-05', '08:01:17', 'l'),
(29, 3, '2020-03-06', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(30, 3, '2020-03-07', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(31, 3, '2020-03-08', '08:01:17', 'p'),
(32, 3, '2020-03-09', '08:01:17', 'l'),
(33, 3, '2020-03-10', '08:00:15', 'p'),
(34, 3, '2020-03-11', '08:02:27', 'p');
```

Sample output

```
uid    consecutive
1      4
2      3
3      3
```

> 1 uid consecutive days 4 for 2020-03-01, 2020-03-02, 2020-03-03, 2020-03-04
>   2 uid consecutive days 3 for 2020-03-06, 2020-03-07, 2020-03-08

etc...

How I create a sql for this output?

Comment: 1 is also p for 2020-02-03 to 2020-02-04 and 2020-02-10 - 2020-02-11 so why these not included in your output?

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Comment: I need only max

Comment: just for demo... I need like that.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: 10.4.11-MariaDB-1:10.4.11+maria~bionic-log

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Only ever 1 status per day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WITH
cte1 AS (SELECT uid, `date` - INTERVAL ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY `date` ASC) DAY d
         FROM a
         WHERE status = 'p'),
cte2 AS (SELECT uid, COUNT(*) cnt
         FROM cte1
         GROUP BY uid, d)
SELECT uid, MAX(cnt) consecutive
FROM cte2
GROUP BY uid;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=c52b17e67932af67b096d6c3b3f22de8)